# RestSharp, Twitter. update_with_media cannot authorize

Tags: c#, twitter, restsharp

trying to send Tweet with the image attached, using RestSharp:

```
  _client = new RestClient("https://api.twitter.com")
        {
            Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(Key, Secret, Token, TokenSecret)
        };
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json", Method.POST);

request.AddFile("media", att.File, att.FileName, "base64");
request.AddParameter("status", postStatus.Text);
var result = await _client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
```

The result is "Could not authenticate you" error no - 32
Thanks

UPDATE: All authentication parameters start from oauth_ and go in alphabetical order, the token, token secret, app key and app key secret are correct, the update status without media works perfectly.

UPDATE 2:

Solution

```
 var request = new RestRequest("/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json", Method.POST);
        request.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;


        request.AddParameter("status", message, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
        request.AddFile("media[]", file, filename, "application/octet-stream");

        var result = _client.Execute(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a problem with restsharp 104.4 (version in Nuget as of time of writing)

We hit the same problem, but your solution above did not work for us. The UrlSegment parameter fails on a status update, and while it does not fail on a call to update_with_media, it also does not post the status, just the picture.

The problem is with OAuth1Authenticator, it does ***not*** ignore non-oauth POST or GET parameters, hence the authentication errors above, and why the URL segment parameter "works".

To fix this, get the latest version of RestSharp from [GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) and use that instead.

For those interested, the checkin involved was only made a month or so after the release and can be found [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/commit/673b60b7ed4ea3d3f26ecdc27e37654b032c6ede#diff-7574fb0741c69a58246a765e316ded74).